# How to open a local file from asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to open a file on a network drive. This is an old ASP.NET app that for some unknown reason is failing now.

```
Dim MyFile as System.Web.HttpPostedFile
MyFile.PostedFile("\\\\server\\path\\",fileName)
Dim Report as DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridView
Report.DataBind()
```

When the code gets to Report.DataBind() an exception is thrown:

```
"Cannot bulk load because the file "\\\\server\\path\\file.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 161(The specified path is invalid.)."
```

if I change the path to \server\path\file.csv I get Network path was not found.

In other words, how do I open a file on a local machine from an ASP.NET application?

I get the same error running the app on the web server and from my local machine. The file can be opened both from the web server and from my local machine. Just not by the application.

Comment: the path is `\\server\path\file.csv` VB.NET is escaping the slash with prepending another

Comment: When I changed it to \\server\path\file.csv I get Network path not found. Yet for sure that is the network path.

Comment: Does the process that's running IIS (not you or the user that's logged on) have authority to get to that network path?

Comment: The files and locations are accessible to Everyone.

Comment: The files may have rights for "Everyone" but that doesn't necessarily mean the service account has rights to *any* network resources.  There are accounts that are limited to the local machine.

Comment: Yes, we are looking into that right now. The error is a SQL Server error when it does the bulk insert.